# Android lost some apps - how do I dl Whatsapp again?

Tags: applications

My HTC Evo 4G piece of trash all of a sudden deleted some of my contacts and apps - including the app market (google play?).  How do I get Whatsapp back - which I paid for through paypal - if I can't access the market store?  Google play asks me to sign in with a gmail account - but I didn't use a gmail account when I bought the app so it doesn't show up when I sign in.

Comment: So you didn't use your GMail account to sign in, and payed using Paypal? For even one of the two, it cannot have been *Google Play* where you did that, as it required logging in with your GMail account long before the first version of WhatsApp became available. And they never accepted Paypal for payments. So you must have been in a different universe then.

Answer (score 2):

You can pay for Whatsapp with PayPal on their own site, so it must have been from there.  You can download the app here...

http://www.whatsapp.com/android/

and, as it says on that page...

> If you already paid for the service you will not be asked to pay for it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you bought it with Paypal, it must not have been through the market.   Suggest you contact the developer for advice.